# Domino 9.0.1 Realtime Replication pool is full

Tags: lotus-domino

We are running a cluster of 4 Domino servers on version 9.0.1 on windows.
On a daily basis the console of every server is spammed with the following message.

`A040:0002-159C 05-04-2017 09:17:26 Cluster Replicator is not replicating all databases: Insufficient memory - Realtime Replication pool is full`

when this message occurs the cluster is broken for certain databases. 
We are unable to find any information on what this message means or how to debug/solve this problem.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions.  This question might belong over at ServerFault: http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ibm-domino.

Comment: How many `Replicators` have you defined in `notes.ini`?

Comment: Also **Cluster_Replicators**?

Comment: Replicators is not set in the ini but CLUSTER_REPLICATORS=2